# Calculate volume of a cylinder with user input

Tags: c++, performance, beginner

I'm looking for a **fast** OR **simple** way to calculate the volume of a user-entered cylinder.  Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    long double pi = acos(-1);
    cout.precision(1000);
    long double radius;
    long double volume;
    long double height;
    cout << "Hello to the cylinder volume solver!" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the cylinder's radius: ";
    cin >> radius;
    long double radius_sq = radius * radius;
    cout << endl << "Please enter the cylinder's height: ";
    cin >> height;
    volume = pi * radius_sq * height;
    cout << endl << "The cylinder's volume is " << volume << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's obvious to see that I'm a new programmer from the way I wrote this....which is why I want to learn from **your** remarks.

Comment: Well, not much improvement regarding speed/simplicity, but some _real world_ / _production ready_ program would have some input error checking. In other words, your code looks _hypothetical_ for me.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please note that we review code and suggest improvements. That's not the same as showing you "our submissions", though it does happen that answers demonstrate alternative implementations. In any case I hope you'll get great tips.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Janos, thank you for the clarification, I guess I was expecting something a little different. :)

Comment: How fast can you type, and how fast can you read? Speed is totally irrelevant for a program of this nature. You should go for the most maintainable code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your implementation is quite simple,
but a bit hard to read:

- It's a wall of code, with no vertical spacing to visual separate closely related groups
- The ordering of statements is haphazard, with no discernible underlying logic

Consider this alternative:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

long double calculateCylinderVolume(long double radius, long double height)
{
    return acos(-1) * radius * radius * height;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello to the cylinder volume solver!\n";

    std::cout << "Please enter the cylinder's radius: ";
    long double radius;
    std::cin >> radius;

    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the cylinder's height: ";
    long double height;
    std::cin >> height;

    std::cout.precision(1000);
    std::cout << "\nThe cylinder's volume is "
        << calculateCylinderVolume(radius, height) << ".\n";
}
```

Notice that:

- variables are not declared sooner than really needed
- the `std::cout.precision(1000);` is delayed until it's actually needed
- the blank lines visually separate the closely related statements, improving readability

Other minor improvements:

- [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/641955) is considered bad practice
- `return 0` at the end of `main` is unnecessary
- `\n` is more efficient than `std::endl`
- [`#include <cmath>` instead of `#include <math.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656459/641955), as pointed out by [@FredLarson](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54015/fred-larson)

Comment: Hmm, why not simply `std::cout << "\nThe cylinder's volume is " << calculateCylinderVolume(radius, height) << ".\n";`?

Comment: `std::endl` flushes the buffer as well as adding a newline, right? Is there a reason to not flush the buffer, or would you describe that as one of those things you only do if you need to?

Comment: @Dannnno Right. Do when you need to. It's not a big deal though, revised the text a bit to say "minor improvements" instead of "improvements". Another reason I like `\n` better because it's shorter, especially when there's already a `"..."` that I can just add to.

Comment: Note that `std::endl` only flushes the buffer if `std::cout` is buffered, which it isn't unless you redirect it.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for what you would create, but I guess a slight improvement is alright.

Comment: Should use `#include <cmath>` instead of `#include <math.h>` too.

Comment: "using namespace std is considered practice" -- Wrong. The only real agreed upon bad practice is using it in a header file.

Answer (score 3):

@janos ' answer is very comprehensive, I have just one point to add: Whenever you have very similar pieces of code, you should consider abstracting the similarity out:

The block:

```
std::cout << "Please enter the cylinder's radius: ";
long double radius;
std::cin >> radius;
```

Is very simlar to:

```
std::cout << "\nPlease enter the cylinder's height: ";
long double height;
std::cin >> height;
```

To avoid repeating the same logic twice and to show your intent at a higher level, you may write a function (procedure):

```
long double doubleInput(std::string prompt) 
{
    std::cout << prompt;
    long double x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}
```

Now `main` is shorter and more readable:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello to the cylinder volume solver!\n";

    long double radius = doubleInput("\nPlease enter the cylinder's radius: ");

    long double height = doubleInput("\nPlease enter the cylinder's height: ");

    std::cout.precision(1000);
    std::cout << "\nThe cylinder's volume is "
        << calculateCylinderVolume(radius, height) << ".\n";
}
```